# Start Safari with tabs, but open new window with start or blank page?

Tags: macos, safari

I'd like the following behavior:

- when I start Safari, I'd like a window with a preselected set of tabs opened (this is easily done through preferences)
- when I then open a new window (⌘-N) I'd like it to open with either a blank window or the start page (either would be acceptable).  Right now it opens with that set of tabs again.

But I can't figure out how to accomplish the second bullet in Preferences.  New windows open with the start set of tabs, which is not what I want.  Suggestions?

(fyi, what I'm trying to achieve is how Chrome behaves, but I'm switching to Safari for my personal use)